# Why I don't get anything from the POST request of Nearbee?

Tags: json, post, postman, beacon

I tried to send beacon's information as a POST request to Nearbee API using the guide they provided [Make beacon detected by Nearbee](https://docs.beaconstac.com/nearbee/how-your-beacons-can-trigger-notifications-on-nearbee), and I saw no response from the API after I hit the send button.
[image: Postman client].

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The status-code of your request indicates a successful request:
[image: Screenshot]

Please try to fire a GET Request against this ressource, to check if its created successfully.